# Thymeleaf: Use #dates.format() function for format date with internatinalization.

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am using `Thymeleaf #dates.format()` function for format date in view layer. I create one internatinalization properties file for pic the date format. i am using `#dates.format(date, (#{app.dateformat}))` function like this. but `Thymeleaf` throw an parse exception. Because thymeleaf now resolve the `app.dateformat`. How i use date format internationalization way in thymeleaf. Following is an exception:

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1043E:(pos 37): Unexpected token. Expected 'identifier' but was 'lcurly({)'
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should use this syntax instead :

```
${#dates.format(date, #messages.msg('app.dateformat'))}
```

> `#messages` : utility methods for obtaining externalized messages inside variables expressions, in the same way as they would be obtained using #{...} syntax.

[Source](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html)

Comment: can I used this sintax in version 2.1 ?

Comment: works for me in this case: ```th:classappend="${#httpServletRequest.requestURI.endsWith(#messages.msg('link.app.public.legal.about-us'))}```