# Mapping MySql Date into java object

Tags: java, mysql, database, date, datetime

in my MySql database I store date as DATE type so I store only YYYY-MM-DD without any information about time (in the other table I use DATETIME to store also time information).
My entity is :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "clientlicense", catalog = "ats")
public class ClientLicense implements java.io.Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Integer idClientLicense;
    private Date startDate;
    private Date endDate;
    private int counter;
    private String macAddress;
    private String cpuId;
```

But when i get `startDate` and `endDate` from my WebUi I receive even the time like 2016-01-29 00:00:00.0
How can I store only the date as into database? Do I have to work in my HTML code?Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with @Temporal JPA annotations.

Anotating your field and changing the type should help:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)  
private java.util.Date startDate;
```

The valid values are:

```
TemporalType.DATE
TemporalType.TIME
TemporalType.TIMESTAMP
```

It is equivalent of

```
DATE – equivalent of java.sql.Date
TIME – equivalent of java.sql.Time
TIMESTAMP – equivalent of java.sql.Timestamp
```

Answer (score 0):

Your entity mapping seems ok to me. The `java.util.Date` class ships also time information.

You will need to format the date object on the web tier. The implementation depends on the technology you are using on the front-end.

For example if you are on a plain JSP page you could format with a `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` object.

Comment: the only problem is that this date field is into an object with different fields, I'm using thymeleaf with this code <td th:text="${license.startDate}"></td> where license is an element of a list

Comment: @luca Maybe this is what you are looking for ;)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28808838/ . In your case this could be something like that: <td th:text="${#dates.format(license.startDate, 'dd/MMM/yyyy')}"/>