# Thymeleaf: how use the dates.format method with i18n through object model

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am working with `Spring Framework` and `Thymeleaf` 3.0.9.RELEASE

About a list report, In a `@Controller` exists the following:

```
model.addAttribute("personas", personaService.findAll());
model.addAttribute("dateFormatPattern", "date.format.pattern");
```

I have read the following:

- [Thymeleaf: Use #dates.format() function for format date with internatinalization.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28808838/thymeleaf-use-dates-format-function-for-format-date-with-internatinalization)

Thus in the view exists the following:

```
<tbody>
  <tr th:each="persona : ${personas}" >
    <td th:text="${personaStat.count}">###</td>
    <td th:text="${persona.id}">###</td>
    <td th:text="${persona.nombre}">###</td>
    <td th:text="${persona.apellido}">###</td>
    <td th:text="${#dates.format(persona.fecha, #messages.msg('date.format.pattern'))}">###</td>
```

Until here `"${#dates.format(persona.fecha, #messages.msg('date.format.pattern'))}"` works fine.

Thus from:

- `model.addAttribute("dateFormatPattern", "date.format.pattern")`

you can see that `date.format.pattern` (the *value* of the *attribute*) is used **directly** in `#messages.msg('date.format.pattern')`.

Thus until here `model.addAttribute("dateFormatPattern", "date.format.pattern")` is useless or is not need it

I want to know (*if is possible*) how would be the correct syntax to use the `dateFormatPattern` (the *key* of the *attribute*) instead, it to expect that `Thymeleaf` retrieve the `date.format.pattern` value and then retrieve the correct pattern from the `.properties` file.

**Reason:** the scenario is where there is a high potential possibility to change `date.format.pattern` value to other and thus it to be reflected through many views (`html` files about reports where the `Date` field is used) **than** the `dateFormatPattern` key instead.

Thus if `date.format.pattern` is changed to `date.format.abc.pattern` it should be in the server side, not for each `.html` file. Therefore `dateFormatPattern` (the *key* of the *attribute*) remains without changes

Comment: Can you clarify the last two paragraphs?  Are you looking to provide the date format from the controller/service or from the properties file?  What do you mean by `through many views`?

Comment: Unless I am misunderstanding, would this work? `<td th:text="${#dates.format(persona.fecha, #messages.msg(dateFormatPattern)}">###</td>`

Comment: About `through many views` I mean many `html` files about reports where a `Date` field appears. About your suggested snippet code, I have tried from the begining, it fails. That is the idea, you understood correctly, use the `dateFormatPattern` directly and expect then that `date.format.pattern` be used and then retrieve the correct pattern from the `.properties` file. Changed the latest paragraph and added a new one for a better understanding